# Importing PAF file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, parsing, postal-code, paf

I recently purchased PAF files from the Royal Mail. I've received them all but now need to import the contents into a MySQL database.

After taking a look at the files there seems to be no common delimiter or way to determine the individual columns.

Can anyone please provide any insight into the format of a PAF file so I can build a parser?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read [this PDF file](ftp://ftp.royalmail.com/Downloads/public/cmwalk/doc/active/doc21800003/PAF_Digest_Dec_03.pdf) taken from [main website](http://www.pafroyalmailpostcodes.co.uk/): it has everything you need to create a parser IMO.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I'd read that previously but couldn't find the information I required. I was hoping there was a delimiter (ie tab-delimited) but turns out each column is X characters long so I've gone with using the field length to split the relevant info out.

Comment: fyi, both those links are broken

Comment: @MarkWorrall: I understand, but this answer is from 2012! And I couldn't have included PDF file in my answer, so the link was the only suitable solution.